# Unknown CSS code in theme causing image to blur

Tags: wordpress

The wordpress theme I have, NeoBeat is causing my logo at top to be blurry.

My site is earthcry.net

The CSS for the image above is

```
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 0;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually being caused by this css here which is reducing the size and causing the blur:

```
#qodef-page-header .qodef-header-logo-link img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto 0;
    width: auto; // Comment this out or delete
    max-height: 100%; // Comment this out or delete
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
```

If you get rid of those, it shows at it's intended size.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a relatively common issue with using the (*relatively* old hat) method of vertical centering with absolute positions. A quick search here, The Goog, The duck site, etc, will show many results for "blurry `<element>` with transforms`.

The easiest and most pragmatic way to deal with this is to not use the "absolute/50%/transform -50%" method to center elements, and upgrade to using `flex`, `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`. There's all sorts of hacky ways to fix the blur, but you'll need to cycle through them and find which works for you (basically, it's being perfectly centered in a 69px tall element so it's got half a pixel on each side of center to deal with that it can't place, so it aliases it.)

However, with all of that said, it looks like you don't actually **need** a centering mechanism at all.

> All you need to do is remove the actual position overrides and transforms. Here's your logo as it stands (it seems to be correct on mobile).

[image: Your logo with the centering]

If you instead just used:

```
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;
```

It would look just fine: [image: Updated logo CSS]

Just remove the `top, left` and vendor-prefixed `transform: translateY` and you should be good to go.

(The previews in the answer may be blurry, click on them to open them up though, I promise the latter one is crisp, lol)